# vba user defined operator in user defined fuction

Tags: vba, operators

How do I make it so that the user can define the operator? For example the user will type

```
=iftrue(x+y,">=z",x+y) (much like a sumif or regular if function)
```

I understand I can use a normal if function or use a separate cell to solve for the logic. However the reason I am doing this is because I have a very cpu intensive computation that will have to recalculate rather than returning the already computed value.

This is currently what I have.

```
Function iftrue(Value1, Criteria1, ValueifTrue)

' Function

If Value1 = Criteria1 Then
iftrue = ValueifTrue

Else: iftrue = Value1

End If

End Function
```

Comment: enumerate all the possible operators and use that with a select case

Comment: The value will be computed one way or another. What make you think (without even testing!) that one way is less/more CPU-intensive than another?

Comment: =if((x+y)>=z,z,(x+y)) In this case if the answer is false it will have to recalculate the answer. I assume that in my udf the (x+y) value will be stored and returned if false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modified versions of your code will do I guess, try it out..

```
Function IfTrue(Value1, Criteria1, ValueifTrue)
    'Function to Evaluate Calculation'

    If Evaluate(Value1 & Criteria1) Then
        IfTrue = ValueifTrue
    Else
        IfTrue = Value1
    End If

End Function
```

This is just the basic idea, you might want to develop on this !

Comment: @vba4all - Thanks for the pointer. I was thinking this as Access VBA. For Excel it is Evaluate. Thanks for that. :)